# Trigonometry Mind Blank

Tags: trigonometry

Hey guys I'm a bit rusty with my math. I have four coordinates. I have found all the lengths of of distance between the four coordinates however now I want to calculate each of those 8 individual angles, but I can't remember how.

As shown:

[image]

How would I do this?

Cheers :)

Comment: Have you learned cosine law, or the vector dot product?

Comment: Not at all. Whys that?

Comment: @DuncanPalmer What in trigonometry you are allowed to use ?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

This law will allow you to solve all the angles when you know the lenghts of the triangle sides. So from

$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cdot cos \gamma $ just solve what $cos \gamma$ is and then take the arccosine.